# Bluetooth Simple Secure Pairing in Android 6.0 not working

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am making a Bluetooth capable device using `TI's CC2564 module`. Before updating to Android 6.0, I could pair my phone (Nexus 5) with the device using `Simple Secure Pairing (SSP)` with no issues. Ever since I updated to Android 6.0, my phone would not pair with the device.

The debug terminal attached to `CC2564 module` shows that a link key is generated, but Android does not show it in its list of paired devices, as it used to with Android 5.0. I tried another phone running Android 4.1, and my Bluetooth capable laptop, and both pair with the device.

Also, if I change settings in CC2564 to pair using a PIN code, then my phone does pair with it. My question is, has something changed in Android 6.0 in terms of SSP functionality? I searched on Google but couldn't find any relevant answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by changing the name of the BT module. Out of the box it's name is set to null, for some reason it was causing an issue in pairing. Changing it gives proper pairing.